# Event being Raised

Tags: java

making a small chat app...
but since im coming from a VB back ground i was wondering is there a way to do this in Java.
when a Client(node) writes a message to me, i read the inputStream via a loop.
but, isnt there a way to raise an event the moment some message has come into my system rather than being running the loop through out? isnt that an efficient method?
Like how in VB,the moment a stream is being received an event is raised, 
so in Java- is there something like a key/action listener for a stream that is coming in?
pls see my code...

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
Socket s = ss.accept();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));



    String str,str1;


    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

Basically when idle the loop shouldnt keep excecuting cause i feel that is inefficient? advise?
or do i start it in a new thread? how would a messaging software handle this efficiently.. any ideas?
thanx in advance guys. im like a bigenner

**UPDATE:** I later on realised that my concepts in Java were totally wrong, I totally understand my confusion, and this actually was a NOT required question. Thanks guys

Comment: Typically, a thread is started for each connection, or asynchronous IO is used.

Comment: So are you saying that the loop isnt occupying resources when there is not data coming in? So i dont need some kinda an eventListner for an incoming stream?

Comment: Where did I say that? What I said is that, typically, to handle several connections at the same time, one thread per connection is used, or asynchronous IO is used. The loop is obviously blocking the thread until it completes. That may or may not be a problem. If you have a single connection, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

`br.readLine()` is going to block your thread if no data is available. This means there's no unnecesary looping.

Comment: ok.. so how do you suppose i proceed...
if i put this in my psvm... then what about my statements below?

Comment: I dint clearly understand...
when you say..."is going to Block your thread" doesnt that mean nothing can run untill br.readline() is done? thats bad, right?
but then you say..."no unnecesary looping"... doesnt that mean resources arent jammed? so isnt that good?
im confused with the jargons you used